# Getting return value from stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Validate]
@a varchar(50),
@b varchar(50) output

AS

SET @Password = 
(SELECT Password
FROM dbo.tblUser
WHERE Login = @a)

RETURN @b
GO
```

This compiles perfectly fine. I want to execute this query and get the return value. My code is below:

```
  SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyLocalSQLServer"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlcomm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Validate", SqlConn);

        string returnValue = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            SqlConn.Open();
            sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@a", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param.Value = Username;
            sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(param);



            SqlParameter retval = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;


            string retunvalue = (string)sqlcomm.Parameters["@b"].Value;
```

Note: Exception handling cut to keep the code short. Everytime I get to the last line, null is returned. What's the logic error with this code?

Answer (score 96):

Mehrdad makes some good points, but the main thing I noticed is you *never run the query*...

```
SqlParameter retval = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.VarChar);
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery(); // MISSING
string retunvalue = (string)sqlcomm.Parameters["@b"].Value;
```

Comment: In the last line, could you have replaced `sqlcomm.Parameters["@b"]` with `retval`?

Comment: You should try it to see.

Comment: I'm not asking a question about code I'm working on, I'm trying to help you improve your answer for future readers.

Answer (score 63):

```
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

`ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` should be used for the "return value" of the procedure, not output parameters. It gets the value returned by the SQL `RETURN` statement (with the parameter named `@RETURN_VALUE`).

Instead of `RETURN @b` you should `SET @b = something`

By the way, return value parameter is always `int`, not string.

Answer (score 14):

I was having tons of trouble with the return value, so I ended up just selecting stuff at the end.

The solution was just to select the result at the end and return the query result in your functinon.

In my case I was doing an exists check:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT RoleName FROM dbo.Roles WHERE @RoleName = RoleName)) 
    SELECT 1
ELSE
    SELECT 0
```

Then

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "RoleExists";
    return (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar()
}
```

You should be able to do the same thing with a string value instead of an int.

Answer (score 5):

This is building on [Joel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/706399/241211) and [Mehrdad's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/706363/241211) answers: you're never binding the parameter of the `retval` to the `sqlcommand`. You need a

```
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(retval);
```

and to make sure you're running the command

```
sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I'm also not sure why you have 2 return value strings (`returnValue` and `retunvalue`).

Answer (score 4):

You say your SQL compiles fine, but I get: Must declare the scalar variable "@Password".

Also you are trying to return a varchar (@b) from your stored procedure, but SQL Server stored procedures can only return integers.

When you run the procedure you are going to get the error:

'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'x' to data type int.'

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple problems here:

1. It is not possible. You are trying to return a varchar. Stored
   procedure return values can only be integer expressions. See
   official RETURN documentation:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx.
2. Your `sqlcomm` was never executed. You have to call
   `sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();` in order to execute your command.

---

Here is a solution using OUTPUT parameters. This was tested with:

- Windows Server 2012
- .NET v4.0.30319
- C# 4.0

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Validate]
    @a varchar(50),
    @b varchar(50) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @b AS varchar(50) = (SELECT Password FROM dbo.tblUser WHERE Login = @a)
    SELECT @b;
END
```

```csharp
SqlConnection SqlConn = ...
var sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("Validate", SqlConn);

string returnValue = string.Empty;

try
{
    SqlConn.Open();
    sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@a", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.Value = Username;
    sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(param);

    SqlParameter output = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    ouput.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery(); // This line was missing

    returnValue = output.Value.ToString();

    // ... the rest of code

} catch (SqlException ex) {
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: You might need to add length of varchar as `sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.VarChar,50);` here 50 is length.

Answer (score 4):

When we return a value from Stored procedure without select statement.
We need to use "ParameterDirection.ReturnValue" and "ExecuteScalar" command to get the value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IsEmailExists
    @Email NVARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF EXISTS(SELECT Email FROM Users where Email = @Email)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 0 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END
END
```

**in C#**

```
GetOutputParaByCommand("IsEmailExists")

public int GetOutputParaByCommand(string Command)
        {
            object identity = 0;
            try
            {
                mobj_SqlCommand.CommandText = Command;
                SqlParameter SQP = new SqlParameter("returnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
                SQP.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                mobj_SqlCommand.Parameters.Add(SQP);
                mobj_SqlCommand.Connection = mobj_SqlConnection;
                mobj_SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                identity = Convert.ToInt32(SQP.Value);
                CloseConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                CloseConnection();
            }
            return Convert.ToInt32(identity);
        }
```

We get the returned value of SP "IsEmailExists" using above c# function.

Answer (score 3):

This SP looks very strange. It does not modify what is passed to @b. And nowhere in the SP you assign anything to @b. And @Password is not defined, so this SP will not work at all.

I would guess you actually want to return @Password, or to have SET @b = (SELECT...)

Much simpler will be if you modify your SP to (note, no OUTPUT parameter):

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Validate] @a varchar(50)

AS

SELECT TOP 1 Password FROM dbo.tblUser WHERE Login = @a
```

Then, your code can use cmd.ExecuteScalar, and receive the result.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things to fix about this.  First set up the stored procedure to store the value in the output ( not return ) parameter.

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Validate]
@a varchar(50),
@b varchar(50) output

AS

SET @b = 
(SELECT Password
FROM dbo.tblUser
WHERE Login = @a)

RETURN
GO
```

This will but the password into @b and you will get it as a return parameter.  Then to get it in your C# do this:

```
SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyLocalSQLServer"].ConnectionString.ToString());
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlcomm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Validate", SqlConn);

    string returnValue = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        SqlConn.Open();
        sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@a", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = Username;
        sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(param);



        SqlParameter retval = new SqlParameter("@b", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(retval);

        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlConn.Close();

        string retunvalue = retval.Value.ToString();
     }
```

Comment: I think that this should be "retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output"

Answer (score 3):

May be this will help.

Database script:

```
USE [edata]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertNewUser](
 @neuname NVARCHAR(255),
 @neupassword NVARCHAR(255),
 @neuposition NVARCHAR(255)
 )

AS

BEGIN 

BEGIN TRY

 DECLARE @check INT;

 SET @check = (SELECT count(eid) FROM eusers WHERE euname = @neuname);

IF(@check = 0)

INSERT INTO  eusers(euname,eupassword,eposition)
VALUES(@neuname,@neupassword,@neuposition);

DECLARE @lastid INT;

SET @lastid = @@IDENTITY;

RETURN @lastid;


END TRY


BEGIN CATCH

SELECT ERROR_LINE() as errline,
       ERROR_MESSAGE() as errmessage,
       ERROR_SEVERITY() as errsevirity

END CATCH

END
```

Application configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="conStr" value="Data Source=User\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=edata;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Data Access Layer (DAL):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace DAL
{
    public static class DAL
    {
        public static SqlConnection conn;

        static DAL()
        {


            conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conStr"].ToString());
            conn.Open();


        }


    }
}
```

Business Logic Layer(BLL):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DAL;
namespace BLL
{
    public static class BLL
    {


        public static int InsertUser(string lastid, params SqlParameter[] coll)
        {

            int lastInserted = 0;

            try
            {


                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();

                comm.Connection = DAL.DAL.conn;


                foreach (var param in coll)
                {

                    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

                }

                SqlParameter lastID = new SqlParameter();
                lastID.ParameterName = lastid;
                lastID.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                lastID.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                comm.Parameters.Add(lastID);

                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                comm.CommandText = "InsertNewUser";

                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                lastInserted = (int)comm.Parameters[lastid].Value;

            }

            catch (SqlException ex)
            {


            }

            finally {

                if (DAL.DAL.conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed) {

                    DAL.DAL.conn.Close();
                }

            }           

            return lastInserted;

        }

    }
}
```

Implementation :

```
BLL.BLL.InsertUser("@lastid",new SqlParameter("neuname","Ded"),
                 new SqlParameter("neupassword","Moro$ilka"),
                 new SqlParameter("neuposition","Moroz")
                 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed up the concept of the Return Value and Output variable.
1- Output Variable:

```
Database----->:
create proc MySP
@a varchar(50),
@b varchar(50) output
AS
SET @Password = 
(SELECT Password
FROM dbo.tblUser
WHERE Login = @a)

C# ----->:

SqlConn.Open();
sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@a", SqlDbType.VarChar);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;//This is optional because Input is the default

param.Value = Username;
sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(param);

SqlParameter outputval = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.VarChar);
outputval .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output//NOT ReturnValue;


string outputvalue = sqlcomm.Parameters["@b"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I like this but it seems like "SET @Password" ought to be "SET @b"

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you need to pass `Username` and `Password` to **Stored Procedure** and know whether login is successful or not and check if any error has occurred in **Stored Procedure**.

```
public bool IsLoginSuccess(string userName, string password)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection SQLCon = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnector"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand();
        SQLCon.Open();
        sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcomm.CommandText = "spLoginCheck"; // Stored Procedure name
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", userName); // Input parameters
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password); // Input parameters

        // Your output parameter in Stored Procedure           
        var returnParam1 = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@LoginStatus",
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
            Size = 1                    
        };
        sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(returnParam1);

        // Your output parameter in Stored Procedure  
        var returnParam2 = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@Error",
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
            Size = 1000                    
        };

        sqlcomm.Parameters.Add(returnParam2);

        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        string error = (string)sqlcomm.Parameters["@Error"].Value;
        string retunvalue = (string)sqlcomm.Parameters["@LoginStatus"].Value;                    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return false;
}
```

Your connection string in `Web.Config`

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlConnector"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Databasename;User id=yourusername;Password=yourpassword"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And here is the **Stored Procedure** for reference

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spLoginCheck
    @Username Varchar(100),
    @Password Varchar(100) ,
    @LoginStatus char(1) = null output,
    @Error Varchar(1000) output 
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN

            SET @Error = 'None'
            SET @LoginStatus = ''

            IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EMP_MASTER WHERE EMPNAME=@Username AND EMPPASSWORD=@Password)
            BEGIN
                SET @LoginStatus='Y'
            END

            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @LoginStatus='N'
            END

        END
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        BEGIN           
            SET @Error = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        END
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

you must then ensure your stored procedure has

```
return @RETURN_VALUE;
```

at the end of the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are trying to get is not a return value but an output parameter. You need to change parametere direction to Output.

```
SqlParameter retval = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.VarChar);
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.ExecuteNonquery();
string retunvalue = (string)sqlcomm.Parameters["@b"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

**For .net core 3.0 and dapper:**

If your stored procedure returns this:

```
select ID, FILE_NAME from dbo.FileStorage where ID = (select max(ID) from dbo.FileStorage);
```

Then in c#:

```
 var data = (_dbConnection.Query<FileUploadQueryResponse>
              ("dbo.insertFile", whateverParameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)).ToList();
 var storedFileName = data[0].FILE_NAME;
 var id = data[0].ID;
```

As you can see, you can define a simple class to help with retrieving the actual values from dapper's default return structure (which I found impossible to work with):

```
public class FileUploadQueryResponse
  {
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FILE_NAME { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

This Line of code returns Store StoredProcedure returned value from SQL Server

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;                
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Atfer Execution of query value will returned from SP

```
id = (int)cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value;
```