# how to read returned values from sql function

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting return value from stored procedure in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706361/getting-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp)

im using the following sql function in a c# winform application

```
create function dbo.GetLookupValue(@value INT)
returns varchar(100)
as begin
  declare @result varchar(100)

  select
    @result = somefield
  from 
    yourtable
  where 
    ID = @value;

  return @result
end
```

my question is: how can i read the returned @result in c#?

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a statement like `SELECT dbo.(function)` to retrieve the value - something like this:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=TEST;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.GetLookupValue(42)", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();
}
```

This will execute the function and return the result value to your C# app.

Comment: How to do the same thing if I use .edmx e.i. object context? I need to call a function that return an int value.