# Fetch return value from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

How to fetch the return value from a stored procedure?

[image]

I noticed that the stored procedure returns an integer on its own. I need to fetch it in C#.

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Well you need to tell how you are calling the SP, some code would be helpful

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of Return parameter in C# to get that value. Like as below

```
SqlParameter retval = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@return_value", SqlDbType.VarChar);
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
string retunvalue = (string)sqlcomm.Parameters["@return_value"].Value;
```

Note your procedure must return a value to be able to fetch it:

```
create procedure [dbo].[usp_GetNewSeqVal]
       @SeqName nvarchar(255)
 as begin 
    declare @NewSeqVal int
    select @NewSeqVal  =1
   ---other statement
    return @NewSeqVal
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Following Code:

```
SqlParameter retval = sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.VarChar);
retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery(); // MISSING
string retunvalue = (string)sqlcomm.Parameters["@b"].Value;
```

For further reference check link: [Getting return value from stored procedure in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706361/getting-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

In your SP, you need to return `KategoriId`. By default SP returns the number of rows affected by the latest insert, update or delete statement.

And mke sure you use proper data type in C# and in database column `KategoriId` to make this work. I had problems in past when database column was `Decimal` and I tried to assign the return value to an `int` and it never worked.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `output` parameter in store procedure  or use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: This is just all wrong: `ExecuteScalar` returns a single row, single column that's being **SELECTED** in the stored procedure - it does **NOT** return the value from the `RETURN x` statement! The `OUTPUT` parameter also has **nothing to do** with the value from the `RETURN` statement.