# How to pass a 3D array to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a 3D string array in C# and I need to send it to a SQL server stored procedure as a parameter so that the procedure performs a select query using WHERE condition from each array row (3 conditions)

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: not really, I've been reading on it online, but I just don't really get it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a table parameter to the stored procedure and pass the input data as a DataTable.

[This article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters) can be a starting pont for sql 2008.

Comment: thanks a lot, but I have one more question.. the procedure is working just fine in sql server, but I can't catch the returned table in c#, any ideas??

Comment: never mind, I've just figured it out!! :) "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386188/return-value-from-stored-procedure-to-c-sharp"