# How to capture the newly inserted row's ID value from C#?

Tags: t-sql

Here's my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spInsertNewTask
@ModuleID               int, 
@Task                   varchar(50), 
@StartDate              date, 
@PlannedEndDate         date, 
@EstimatedEndDate       date, 
@Status                 int,
@Comments               varchar(500),
@Started                bit
AS
INSERT INTO DTasks (ModuleID, Task, StartDate, PlannedEndDate, EstimatedEndDate, Status, Comments, Started, LastUpdated)
VALUES (@ModuleID, @Task, @StartDate, @PlannedEndDate, @EstimatedEndDate, @Status, @Comments, @Started, GETDATE())

RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

When I try to capture the newly created ID, all I'm getting is always 1. How to capture the New row's ID?

```
newID = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In fact I need this new ID for further processing.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`, which returns the number of effected rows, you should use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx), casting the returned `object` to the correct type:

```
newID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

For the above to work, you also need to change the SQL from returning a return value to *select* the value:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

The code example on the page is pretty much what you are looking to do.

---

If you want to keep the return type, you will need to add a return type parameter to the command, execute as non-query as you currently do, then read the value of the return parameter, as described in [Getting return value from stored procedure in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706361/getting-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp).

Comment: I'm getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception.

Comment: Wouldn't that require the value to be returned by `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` (rather than using the `RETURN` keyword?)

Comment: After I changed the key word from RETURN to SELECT, I am getting a different error exception: "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @Richard77 - What is the expected value? Does it for inside the range of an `int`? I'd expect that error if the returned value is not an integer.

Comment: @Obed, while researching other answers, I've found out that the return value is decimal. They suggest that the result be cast twice. Like this (int)(decimal). Now it's working.

Comment: @Richard77 - That's would do it... and it's Oded, not Obed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass [ID] assuming that it is you identity column as output parameter:

In C# you need to add new parameter which is output parameter and at the end of execution to retrieve :

Initialize:

```
    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@ID", 0);
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
```

Retrieve after execution:

```
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(sqlcommand.Parameters["@ID"].Value.ToString());
```

Stored procedure:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spInsertNewTask
        @ID                     INT = NULL OUTPUT,
        @ModuleID               int, 
        @Task                   varchar(50), 
        @StartDate              date, 
        @PlannedEndDate         date, 
        @EstimatedEndDate       date, 
        @Status                 int,
        @Comments               varchar(500),
        @Started                bit
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO DTasks (ModuleID, Task, StartDate, PlannedEndDate, EstimatedEndDate, Status, Comments, Started, LastUpdated)
        VALUES (@ModuleID, @Task, @StartDate, @PlannedEndDate, @EstimatedEndDate, @Status, @Comments, @Started, GETDATE())

        SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END 
    GO
```