# C# return Identity on Insert

Tags: c#, sql

I have a problem, I need to return the identity of the record I have just created in c# and save it as an integerr.
I've seen loads of examples on the internet but I just can't seem to adapt it for what I need.
Any help appreciated

```
cmprawf.CommandText = "INSERT INTO profiion( // Code that inserts in the right place )";
cmprawf.ExecuteNonQuery();
cnTB.Close();
```

Comment: You say you can't adapt any of the loads of examples you've seen, but in that case, answers here won't help you. What specifically have you tried that should work, according to you, but doesn't work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return value from SQL Server Insert command using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319532/return-value-from-sql-server-insert-command-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `SELECT` to your batch and return the newly created identifier:

```
cmprawf.CommandText = "INSERT INTO profiion( // Code that inserts in the right place );" + 
                      "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
int newID = (int)cmprawf.ExecuteScalar();
cnTB.Close();
```

Comment: [`Scope_Identity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) returns `numeric(38,0)` so you cannot cast it to `int` on client-side without casting it in the database. Another approach: cast it to `decimal` with C# first.

Answer (score 1):

Add `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY` to your query, then you can retrieve it via `ExecuteScalar`:

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO profiion( // Code that inserts in the right place );
               ;SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
cmprawf.CommandText = sql;
int newID = (int)cmprawf.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to select the SCOPE_IDENTITY and retrieve it using ExecuteScalar.

`cmprawf.CommandText = "INSERT INTO profiion( // Code that inserts in the right place ); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
int id = cmprawf.ExecuteScalar();
cnTB.Close();`

Answer (score 0):

If your db is SQL Server then

cmprawf.CommandText = "INSERT INTO profiion( // Code that inserts in the right place );SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
int yourId = (int)cmprawf.ExecuteScalar();
cnTB.Close();

You can always view the last part of Microsoft's info on this if you want to use parameters(better)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return value of the sql command. Every stored procedure can have a return value of type int and you can retrieve it as follows :

```
SqlParameter returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
  returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  int id = (int) returnParameter.Value;
```

code is copied from this post's second answer :
[Get Return Value from Stored procedure in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810037/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-asp-net)

Also In your stored procedure you can get the id of the inserted row by calling the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function .