# passing a value from a stored procedure to a variable

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

can someone please help me how to pass a return value from a stored procedure to a variable in c#. I am new in c# and I've been stucked to that problem for about 2 days. here is my code:

```
 private void CheckSmsStatus()
        {
            string stat = null;
            ShortMessage l = new ShortMessage();
            stat.DataSource = l.checksmsstatus_query().Tables[0];
            stat.DisplayMember = "Status";
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: look up "sqlcommand parameters", or search SO...

Comment: look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810037/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-asp-net/14816172#14816172