# Indifferent behaviour when using Execute Reader in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, executereader

I have a stored procedure it returns a name so i need to get the name in in C#

so i just execute the Sp from C# and read the out put using `ExecuteReader()` like below

```
 using (var objCommand = new SqlCommand("SpName", objConnection))
                    {
                        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", Param);
                        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purpose", Purpose);
                        objConnection.Open();
                        objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        using (var reader = objCommand.ExecuteReader())
                        {

                                while (reader.Read())
                                {

                                    objemailsend.Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]);
                                }

                        }
                    }

         objConnection.Close();
```

It gives an exception

> Index Out of range exception

I am sure that the index names are same i mean the Sp also returns the same name

```
Name
----
name1
```

like above

then i tried something like below and now the exception disappears and it returns a numeric value i don't know from where the value coming from and it is not same as my SP result

```
objexample.Name = reader[0].ToString();
```

also tried

```
 using (var reader = objCommand.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                             if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {

                                    objemailsend.Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]);
                                }
}

                        }
```

But the same error

Can you somebody help me to solve my issue.

Comment: *One* name? If so ExecuteScalar or an output param would be simpler

Comment: Side note: `if (reader.Read())` looks better than `while(`

Comment: @AlexK. yes i agree,this is only a sample code and it not a single value it contain more than one, i will insert that values in to a list. this is only a simple example , but when i use this too i did not get result

Comment: @DmitryBychenko sure i will keep in mind that point thank you

Comment: At which line do you get the exception?

Comment: Have you checked there is a "Name" column in the returned data?

Comment: @TimSchmelter objemailsend.Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]); this line , the line that assigns the out put value to local variable

Comment: @PaulF from sql profiler take the query and manuvaly executed in sql management studio

Comment: Put a break point on the line & check the reader values.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: that exception is thrown if ["no column with the specified name was found"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy(v=vs.110).aspx). So you should show us your stored-procedure.

Comment: @PaulF it shows reader has rows true

Comment: Not whether it has rows - but the actual results - the exception would be expected if there is not a "Name" field in the row read.

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes i agree with you,many times i had searched internet for a solution and the same thing is all are saying , i am sure the field name is exact same. but it throws exeption , i dont know what is happening here that is why i posted the question here

Comment: @PaulF agreed , but y sp returns the column with same name .

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: you can use this to see all columns: `String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(i => reader.GetName(i)))` I'm pretty sure that you don't find a `Name`-column

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes sure i will use and let you know

Comment: To be sure what your SP return check on database with parameters:
`exec SpName param1, param2`

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes you are right , there is no column named NAME and the colum names comming here is my sp's catch error deatils column names , but it is strange , when i directly run the sp in sql management studio it results the name

Comment: @TimSchmelter i had check that , and when ever i run the Sp directly in sql management studio it gives correct out put , when i call it through C# it outputs the catch error .i don't know why it happends , you have any idea about this ? please help me

Comment: @TimSchmelter finally i have fixed it , it my query i had included SET ARITHABORT ON on and now the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

[Please check this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810037/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-asp-net)

```
var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("RetVal", SqlDbType.Int);
returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
int id = (int) returnParameter.Value;
```

Comment: without the stored proc we were all guessing

Answer (score 0):

Try retrieving the value using index like   objemailsend.Name =  reader[1].ToString().
Where I have assumed 1 to be the index for name column.
As you are getting the Index Out of range execption this will help because here you are explicitly providing the index for the name column.

```
using (var objCommand = new SqlCommand("SpName", objConnection))
                    {
                        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", Param);
                        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purpose", Purpose);
                        objConnection.Open();
                        objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        using (var reader = objCommand.ExecuteReader())
                        {

                                while (reader.Read())
                                {

                                    objemailsend.Name = Convert.ToString(reader[1]);
                                }

                        }
                    }

         objConnection.Close();
```