# How To Get Set Value From Stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that client provided me

Like:

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[XYZ]
    @Parameter varchar(100),
    @Parameter1 nvarchar(4000) out

   SET @APIString = "Test Test"
```

I have no rights to change this procedure.

When I execute procedure through C# I get a **blank** string from procedure

How to get the `@Parameter1` value in my project?

**C# Code:**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.XYZ", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter", Parameter);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter1", SqlDbType.VarChar,4000);
cmd.Parameters["@Parameter1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

conn.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    String = reader["@Parameter1"] != null ? reader["@Parameter1"].ToString() : "";
}

conn.Close();
```

Comment: Show how you "execute the procedure through C#"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706361/getting-return-value-from-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@Parameter1` is an output parameter. You can get its value the same way you set the values for input parameters, e.g.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.XYZ", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter", inputValue);

// add the output parameter
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Direction =
    ParameterDirection.Output;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

string parameter1 = (string)cmd.Parameters["@Parameter1"].Value;
```

---

You should also use `ExecuteNonQuery` unless the store procedure returns values with a select statement.